# Run script from GRUB menu entry

Tags: linux-kernel, grub

I have created a Debian Live DVD following the excellent guide https://willhaley.com/blog/custom-debian-live-environment/.

I would like to be able to great two grub menu enteries when selected auto login and run a script.

```
    menuentry "Run Script 1" {
        linux /vmlinuz boot=live quiet nomodeset
        initrd /initrd
    }

    menuentry "Run Script 2" {
        linux /vmlinuz boot=live quiet nomodeset
        initrd /initrd
    }
```

How can I pass from grub menu entry the absolute path of a script to run when I auto login as root?

/lib/live/mount/medium/scripts/script1.bash

To auto login I have modified /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service to auto login as root using the above menu items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boot with a custom parameter:

```
linux /vmlinuz .... my_dummy_param=/lib/live/mount/medium/scripts/script1.bash
```

Then later read `/proc/cmdline` and parse it in your login shell startup files, ex. in `.bashrc` for bash shells or `.profile`:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /proc/cmdline
echo "Running $my_dummy_param"
"$my_dummy_param"
```